# How to list of all parameters, return values and others of parents in Doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

I am writing an API documentation for a crop model using Doxygen and would like to copy all parameters, return values, precondition and warnings of parents. In this case, users will be simple to find all useful information in one pae.

I have tried to use \copydetails command which copy the whole detail section into children documentation.

Is it possible to achieve this in current version of Doxygen? Or need to write some new commands?

Please let me know if my question is not clear. Thanks for any suggestion.